# Argument Processing in golang

Tags: rest, go, arguments, command-line-arguments

I will be giving the following as the command to run my go program.

> go run app.go 3001-3005

What this is supposed to do is, run my go Rest api on server ports 3001 to 3005.

This part of my main function which handles this argument.

```
func main() { 
ipfile := os.Args[1:]
s := strings.Split(ipfile, "-")
mux := routes.New() 
mux.Put("/:key1/:value1", PutData)
mux.Get("/profile/:key1", GetSingleData) 
mux.Get("/profile", GetData)
http.Handle("/", mix)
```

Here I will run a for loop and replace the first argument with s[i].

```
http.ListenAndServe(":3000", nil)
}
```

I get the following output:

```
cannot use ipfile (type []string) as type string in argument to strings.Split
```

What datatype does os.args return?
I tried converting it to string and then splitting. Does not work.
Please let me know what is wrong?

Comment: Also: `http.ListenAndServe` is blocking, so you have to fire off each listener in its own goroutine (e.g. as part of a `sync.WaitGroup`) if you want to have three concurrent listeners on different ports.

Comment: Could you tell me how to use sync.Waitgroup in this context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like the error says, `ipfile` is a `[]string`. The `[1:]` slice operation is going to return a slice, even if there's only 1 element.

After checking that `os.Args` has the enough elements, use:

```
ipfile := os.Args[1]
s := strings.Split(ipfile, "-")
```

Comment: Thank you. The error i had was there was an extra ':' after the 1 in ipfile := os.Args[1]